# test the existance of id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I want to search id and id2 of file2. If one of them exists on id and id2 of file1 to fill the column info 2 with information written on info of this line like shown in the figure [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVpfj.png).

I did these lines but nothing works:

```
if (pd.notna(file2['id'])):
    if (file2['id'] == file1['id']):
        file2['info2']= file1['INFO']
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Are DataFrames with same sizes, number of rows? Please add [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: they havent'i the same size . one have 3300 rows, the other with 20 row.

Comment: Please check comment no2 and add mcve.

Comment: i can not put the hole data it is confidential ... I gave this example that describes my problem. Thank you